# UIBarButtonItem causing unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a popover menù on an UIBarButtonItem programmatically, this is the code i write

```
    static func setNavigationRightButton(myView: UIViewController) {

    navBarBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
    navBarBtn.addTarget(myView, action: #selector(pizza.handleFunc(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    navBarBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 33, height: 30)
    navBarBtn.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    //navBarBtn.setTitle("10", for: .normal)
    setCartBadge()
    navBarBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 9)

    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: navBarBtn)
    myView.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
}
```

and this is the action func

```
    func handleFunc(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem!) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShoppingCartPopoverVC") as! ShoppingCartPopoverVC
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100)
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    let popOver = navController.popoverPresentationController
    popOver?.delegate = self
    popOver?.barButtonItem = sender
    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

when i'm here "popOver?.barButtonItem = sender" the app crash with this error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton _viewForPresenting]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faa0b5148f0'

Comment: You have `UIButton` here `navBarBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)` and `func handleFunc(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem!)` expecting `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: that has nothing to do with the crash.

Answer (score 3):

Your target/action is being set to a `UIButton` but your action method specifies a `UIBarButtonItem` instead of a `UIButton` for the sender.

You need to update your action:

```
func handleFunc(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShoppingCartPopoverVC") as! ShoppingCartPopoverVC
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100)
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    let popOver = navController.popoverPresentationController
    popOver?.delegate = self
    popOver?.sourceView = sender
    popOver?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Note the change to parameter and the properties set on the popover controller.